# Memristor Differential Equation Help

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, mathematics, differential-equations, resonance

I'm currently trying to solve the DE that defines charge in a circuit containing an Inductor, Capacitor, Resistor and (crucially) a Memristor. This needs to be able to work for any variable values and ends up being of the form:

$k_1 \cdot y'' + k_2 \cdot y' + k_3 \cdot yy' + k_4 \cdot y = k_5 \cdot \cos(k_6 \cdot x)$

(Hopefully that works, first time using LaTex)

If someone knows whether or not this is even solvable (or has the solution) that would be great, or even just some guidance on how to approach the $yy'$ term along with dealing with all of the unknown constants would be appreciated as well, as that's not something I've come across before.

I'm hoping this is the right place for this post, if not please do let me know.

Comment: this has no analytic solution in terms elementary transcendental functions. You can use perturbation methods if $k_3$ is "small", (to see what is small and what is not you have to scale the $k_6x$ term to be the "unit" so that the terms are not dimensional) or use methods such as the equivalent linearization techniques associated with names such as Krylov-Bogoliubov, describing function,  and several others. As a start, check out the Duffing and van der Pol equations and its solutions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffing_equation  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Pol_oscillator.